# Get the App path without the app name at the end of the app

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I'm using xcode and want to get the path where my app is running without the app name at the end of the path, but i have tried:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
```

it give me the right path where my app is runing but it ends with /my app name, how can i remove the app name?

Comment: Which language (no, C/C++ is not a programming language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **dirname**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{        
    std::string dir = dirname(argv[0]);
    std::cout << dir << std::endl;
}
```

Run application:

```
  $/data/temp/test
```

output:

```
  $/data/temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dirname`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dirname.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dirname) function.

Comment: Could you please provide me any example on how to use it right? it might be simple, but to avoid mistakes

Comment: @JhsajdaHhas See the answer from billz.

Answer (score 1):

use `std::string::find_last_of` to find the last instance of the path seperator (`/` if *nix, `\` if windows) and use `std::string::substr` to copy everything up to that index.

Example :

```
std::string file = argv[0];

std::string path = file.substr(0,file.find_last_of("/"));
```

This should do what you want, barring any silly mistakes in my code

Comment: Could you please show me a small example in code, if you dont mind

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an equivalent of bash `pwd`, you can use:

```
#include <unistd.h>
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
```

Note that if you previously called chdir(). this will not return the path you're looking for.

Comment: Please show me how to use it right to help me and others in future

Comment: dirname() is actually better attitude if you just want to strip the filename from the whole path. getcwd() gives you exactly the same output as shell's pwd, which is current working directory (if unchanged, the directory you called the binary from)